# Adding a month to a date in T SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

How can I add one month to a date that I am checking under the where clause?

```
select *
from Reference
where reference_dt + 1 month
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Reference 
WHERE reference_dt = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, another_date_reference)
```

Comment: Please note that if you use this function with negative values you may get unexpected results for example DATEADD(MM, -1,'2024-03-29'), DATEADD(MM, -1,'2024-03-30'), DATEADD(MM, -1,'2024-03-31') will all give the same result 2024-02-29. Also DATEADD(MM, 1,'2024-02-29') will give 2024-03-29 as a result. So use the function with care.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) function with the following syntax

> DATEADD (datepart, number, date)

In your case, the code would look like this:

```
...
WHERE reference_dt = DATEADD(MM, 1, reference_dt)
```

Answer (score 12):

Use [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
DATEADD(month, 1, reference_dt)
```

Comment: +1 For not using the abbreviation. I would have no idea whether `DATEADD(mm` was adding minutes or months without referring to the docs.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateAdd(m, 1, reference_dt)
```

This will add a month to the column value.

Answer (score 1):

`DATEADD` is the way to go with this

See the W3Schools tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Reference 
WHERE reference_dt = DATEADD(MM, 1, reference_dt)
```

Comment: Almost... `DATEADD (datepart , number , date )`