# How to get date before 3 months from a particular date, say current date in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

How can we deduce the date falling exactly 3 months prior to the current date in SQL Server?

Comment: Hope this link can help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967459/adding-a-month-to-a-date-in-t-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use dateadd

```
select convert(date, dateadd(month,-3,getdate()))
output
16/07/2018 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Dateadd can give the same result for three different dates.

```
Select DateAdd(Month, -3, '2024-05-29')
Select DateAdd(Month, -3, '2024-05-30')
Select DateAdd(Month, -3, '2024-05-31')
```

All give the same result namely 2024-02-29, recognising that 3 months is a quarter using:

```
Select dateAdd(DD, -91, '2024-05-31')
Select dateAdd(DD, -91, '2024-05-30')
Select dateAdd(DD, -91, '2024-05-29')
```

Will give 2024-03-01, 2024-02-29, 2024-02-28 respectively.

So the answer depends on what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`DATEADD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function

```
SELECT DATEADD(M, -3,GETDATE()) AS WithTime,
       CAST(DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS WithoutTime
```

If you are working on newest versions of SQL Server (2012+) I would recommand to use **[`TRY_CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** or **[`TRY_CAST()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** functions.